# Getting started with coding unix commands

Tags: c, unix, systems-programming

I have been learning c and data structures for quite some time now and I wanted to see whether I could apply what I have learnt. I searched a bit and found out that I could start with util linux but, before I could do so, I thought I'd check and perhaps dabble a bit with the code for basic unix commands like "cat". I was able to understand what a part of the code might have been trying to do, but I was not able to understand the entire code as a unit.
For example, in the "cat" code, a pointer to the output buffer and input buffer is declared and is appropriately used, which I could understand. What i could not understand, are parts of code like `io_blksize (stat_buf)` which has no description whatsoever, on what it does. Or how two pointers declared as pointers to the input and output buffers, actually correspond to the input and output buffers ?
So my question being, how do I approach these type of code, how can I understand something that has no description to what it does (in the example given above) and how can I make and implement changes in the code, so that I can see the changes when i run a command ?
(Would really appreciate references or topics I should start with, so that I can relate what I have learnt to how command code's can be modified. I also apologize if the question is to abstract.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a subjective question so my answers will just be my opinion of course.

A good place to start when you run into something you don't recognise while reading source code is the manpages. Each function will generally have a manpage, e.g. `man 2 read` or `man 3 printf`. Beyond that, I feel perhaps you should get more of a foundation in Unix before attempting to read the straight source code, a good book is Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment. I've been working through it myself and am finding my Unix knowledge improving considerably.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Yes, I took a look at  the book and it seems that it does show a lot of correlation. I think this will definitely help me out. Thank you.